# android sqlcipher java.io.FileNotFoundException: icudt46l.zip

Tags: java, android, sqlcipher

The directory structure is as follows

```
Test
    app
        libs
            commons-codec.jar
            guava-r09.jar
            sqlcipher.jar
        src
            main
                java
                jniLibs
                    armeabi
                        libdatabase_sqlcipher.so
                        libsqlcipher_android.so
                        libstlport_shared.so
                    x86
                        libdatabase_sqlcipher.so
                        libsqlcipher_android.so
                        libstlport_shared.so
```

Now, it keeps giving me the Exception `java.io.FileNotFoundException: icudt46l.zip` no matter where I put it.

I have tried putting `assets\icudt46l.zip` in `Test\app`, `Test\app\libs`, `Test\app\src`, `Test\app\src\main`, `Test\app\src\main\jniLibs` but the Exception persists.

Where should I put the folder "assets" which contains the zip file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, it keeps giving me the Exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: icudt46l.zip no matter where I put it.

Given your project structure, put it in `Test/app/src/main/assets/`. IOW, you will need to create an `assets/` directory that is a peer of your `java/` directory, and put the ZIP file in there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. But logcat is still telling me that the icu data file cannot be found, even when the `assets` folder is in `Test\app\src\main`, and is a peer to `java`.

Comment: @user3635998: All I can tell you is that is where assets go, and that structure [works for me in my Android Studio SQLCipher sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/ConstantsSecure-AndroidStudio). Now, in my case, the project has just one module, at the top level, rather than Android Studio's default of putting it in an `app/` directory.

Comment: OK, it's my bad. After changing the emulator from Android API to Google API, it's fine.